# Do I need annotation for inherited data class when I annotate its parent class or interface?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I have something like this:

```kotlin
sealed interface CommonResponse {
    val success: Boolean
    val impUid: String
    val merchantUid: String
    val payMethod: String
    val pgProvider: String
    val pgType: String
}
```

And it needs to be serialized or deserialized. So, I do

```kotlin
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class SuccessResponse (
    override val success: Boolean,
    @SerialName("imp_uid")
    override val impUid: String,
    @SerialName("merchant_uid")
    override val merchantUid: String,
    @SerialName("pay_method")
    override val payMethod: String,
    @SerialName("pg_provider")
    override val pgProvider: String,
    @SerialName("pg_type")
    override val pgType: String,
    @SerialName("paid_at")
    val paidAt: String,
    val amount: String
): PaymentResponse
```

```kotlin
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class FailureResponse (
    override val success: Boolean,
    @SerialName("imp_uid")
    override val impUid: String,
    @SerialName("merchant_uid")
    override val merchantUid: String,
    @SerialName("pay_method")
    override val payMethod: String,
    @SerialName("pg_provider")
    override val pgProvider: String,
    @SerialName("pg_type")
    override val pgType: String,
    @SerialName("error_message")
    val errorMessage: String
): PaymentResponse
```

So, it has a lot of annotations. So, Can I do something like this?

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
sealed interface CommonResponse {
    val success: Boolean
    @SerialName("imp_uid")
    val impUid: String
    @SerialName("merchant_uid")
    val merchantUid: String
    @SerialName("payMethod")
    val payMethod: String
    @SerialName("pg_provider")
    val pgProvider: String
    @SerialName("pg_type")
    val pgType: String
}
```

And then, remove the annotations in child classes

```kotlin
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class SuccessResponse (
    override val success: Boolean,
    override val impUid: String,
    override val merchantUid: String,
    override val payMethod: String,
    override val pgProvider: String,
    override val pgType: String,
    @SerialName("paid_at")
    val paidAt: String,
    val amount: String
): PaymentResponse
```

Is it possible? Or any better way to simplify this?